# MySQL JOIN to show required output

Tags: mysql, join

Is there a way I can select all columns from two tables in MySQL, but only show the data in the end column if a match is found in both tables?

For example…

Main table (contacts)

```
id| token | Name
------------------
1 | ABC   | Test person 1
2 | DEF   | Test person 2
3 | GHI   | Test person 3
```

Subscriptions table (subscribed)

```
id| contact_token
-------------------
1 | ABC
```

Desired output

```
id| token | Name           | contact_token
------------------------------------------
1 | ABC   | Test person 1  | ABC
2 | DEF   | Test person 2  | 
3 | GHI   | Test person 3  |
```

The contents of contact_token is show (ABC) because it appears in both tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is what a LEFT JOIN is for:
You select all records from table contacts and you do a left join on the subscribed one.

```
SELECT subscribed.id,token,name,contact_token
FROM contacts LEFT JOIN subscribed
ON contacts.id = subscribed.id;
```

For the records that are only in the first table you will get NULL in the last column.

Comment: You're going to want a condition for that LEFT JOIN!

Comment: @Arth, ups! I forgot a step in the query :) thanks, I'm fixing!

Comment: Both tables have an id field, you need to qualify the id field in the select list, otherwise you'll get an error. Then our sql statements will be exactly the same :)

Comment: @Shadow seems I'am getting too tired for today ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider storing the subscription data in the main contacts table, unless you can have multiple subscriptions per user. If the latter is the case, then you have to consider if you want to see the subscription tokens within one line in the output or in multiple lines.

The basic query is simple, you need to left join the subscribed table to the contacts:

```
select contacts.id, token, name, contact_token
from contacts left join subscribed
on contacts.id=subscribed.id
```

Comment: That's not always true. In many cases it will be faster to perform a query on the subscribed query with less data. It depends on many factors but it is not what OP is asking.

Comment: I wrote "you should consider". I did not know that this expression was a synonim for "always true".